# How to check array of object has values or undefined-Reactjs, Array

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I am just trying to loop through the  array of object and if the values are empty and undefined and null it should pop up alert message

is there any simple way to find the object of array has values or undefined

tried to search if any post available please post me here

Can any one help me on this

here is the screenshot below

Here i am showing only object which i need to loop through and check if undefined

[image]

Edited

```
handleGobackToBoards =() =>{
const compareWidgetData = this.props.storyboardList.boardList.map((data, key) => {
  if (data.boardId === this.props.selectedBoard.boardId ) {
    data.widgetList.map((widget => {
      if (widget.widgetId) {
        Object.values(widget).map(value => {
          if (value === undefined || value === null || value === "" || value === 0) {
            alert('Empty Data');
          }
          else {
            this.props.manageShowBoard({});
          }
       // });
      }
    }));
  }
});
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know if there is at least 1 value:

- *undefined* or *null* (`== null`)
- or *empty* (`=== ""`)

you should use `findIndex` on object's values.

```
if ( -1 !== Object.values(widget).findIndex( v => v == null || v === "") )
    alert("missing value found!");
```

Note that `find` is not appropriate because you would not know what it means when it return *undefined*.

---

[EDIT with your code]

You misuse `map`. `map` is when you want to return an array of same length and work on its transformed elements. Here your function returns nothing.

If you want to return an array with less elements (e.g. matching an id), use `filter`.

If you want to return anything else (e.g. sum of all elements), use `reduce`.

If you want to return nothing (void) and just loop through array, use `forEach`.

If you want to check if an element has a property, use `find` or `findIndex`.

From what I understand, your function could be:

```
handleGobackToBoards = () => {
    const boardList = this.props.storyboardList.boardList,
          boardId = this.props.selectedBoard.boardId;
    boardList
        .filter( (data) => data.boardId === boardId ) // Get all board with matching id
        .forEach( (data) => {
            data.widgetList
                .filter( (widget) => widget.widgetId ) // Get all widgets that have an id
                .forEach( (widget) => {
                    if ( -1 !== Object.values(widget).findIndex( v => v == null || v === "") ) {
                        alert('Empty Data');
                    }
                    else {
                        this.props.manageShowBoard({});
                    }
                });
        });
}
```

---

[EDIT2] Something that is not equivalent to your code, but I guess closer to what you want to do:

```
handleGobackToBoards = () => {
    const boardList = this.props.storyboardList.boardList,
          boardId = this.props.selectedBoard.boardId,
          board = boardList.find( (data) => data.boardId === boardId ); // Get board with matching id
    if (!board)
        return; // No matching board
    const emptyWidget = board.widgetList.find( (widget) => -1 !== Object.values(widget).findIndex( v => v == null || v === "") );
    if (emptyWidget)
        alert('Empty Data');
    // All widgets have no empty property, show board
    this.props.manageShowBoard({});
}
```

Comment: but any other method to work on if find is not appororiate

Comment: @JMR: yes, use `findIndex` as I suggest. Also, `forEach`, `map` or `reduce` will parse the full array, which you do not want either.

Comment: i have used map , let me paste my answer, please correct me

Comment: @JMR: let me have a look and update my answer with complete code

Comment: @JMR: Now you've got a nice javascript example. You may have to adapt following what you want to do. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Loop the array of widgets and loop through each widget values to check each value:

```
widgetlist.forEach(widget => {
  Object.values(widget).forEach(value => {
    if (value === undefined || value === null || value === "") {
      console.log('Value ', value, ' of widget', widget, ' is empty'); // if you prefer do an alert 
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: if i alert it need to hit 3 times to get back